# Dropwizard - Run init method in class on server start

Tags: java, guice, dropwizard

I'm trying to pull a bunch of data from a database into the application's memory.

I'd like to do this on server startup so that it doesn't slow the application down during runtime.

Is this possible in Dropwizard (using Guice dependency injection)?

Answer (score 0):

I have used a similar approach on my application by using `UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory`
In My Application.Java inside the run method, I have created proxy DAO.

```
public void run(Configuration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
    // run method 
     .
     .
     .

    // At end of the method
    final MyDAOOne myDAOOne = new MyDAOOneImpl(hibernateBundle.getSessionFactory());
    MyDAOOneProxy myDAOOneProxy = new UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory(hibernateBundle).create(MyDAOOneProxy.class, MyDAOOneImpl.class, myDAOOne );

    final MyDAOTwo myDAOTwo = new MyDAOTwoImpl(hibernateBundle.getSessionFactory());
    MyDAOTwoProxy myDAOTwoProxy = new UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory(hibernateBundle).create(MyDAOTwoProxy.class, MyDAOTwoImpl.class, myDAOTwoProxy);

    //Init in memory Cache
    new CacheInitializeServiceImpl(myDAOOneProxy, myDAOTwoProxy);
}
```

Here CacheInitializeServiceImpl Class contains a list of static methods which is return store database data.

Answer (score -1):

A simple approach to load the data at the application startup . In dropwizard you can do this in the run method of your Application Class. Click [here](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.0/docs/getting-started.html#creating-an-application-class) for reference.